# how can i implement polling Service to a Web Server?

Tags: android, service, webserver, polling

I am facing for the first time with a problem in Android: I need a Service that works like a polling.

I have an Activity that has to do POST requests periodically to a web server. In fact, it controls if there is a new message from the person I'm talking to. In practice, the request should return a Boolean TRUE if a new message or FALSE. If TRUE I get some kind of warning on the GUI.

Maybe you can expand it: I have a list view of people with whom I'm talking about and the Service would be required for each user with whom I'm talking to and returns the appropriate notifications (always displayed in a list view, for example). So the result looks like the messages that arrive on facebook in the top toolbar (here we have a list view).

How do I set this procedure? It 'greedy in terms of resources / battery?

thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

The preferred mechanism was instead to have the phone make a request to a server as normal, but for the server to leave the socket open and the request unanswered until it has something to send (or until some timeout elapses, when it sends an 'ask me again' message in case the phone has disappeared into a tunnel or something).

The modern way is with GCM or similar.